# Representing big numbers in source code for readability?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Is there a more human-readable way for representing big numbers in the source code of an application written in C++ or C?

let's for example take the number `2,345,879,444,641` , in C or C++ if we wanted a program to return this number we would do `return 2345879444641`.

But this is not really readable.

In PAWN (a scripting language) for example I can do `return 2_345_879_444_641` or even `return 2_34_58_79_44_46_41` and these both would return the number `2,345,879,444,641`.

This is much more readable for the human-eye.

Is there a C or C++ equivalent for this?

Comment: so how would I represent 286586837272 ? I woul like to read 286_586_837_272 , 1000000000000 was just an example number

Comment: @David It's not the same thing, at least not in C++.  `1e9` has type `double`; `1000000000` has type `int` (or `long`, or `long long`, depending on the implementation).

Comment: Have you considered using hexadecimal notation?

Comment: you want any number in human readable form? I'd suggest putting it in a comment right after in whatever format tickles your pickle

Comment: if this is the only option to go.. well.

Comment: Not standard C++, but some compilers do, or did, allows `$` in numbers, and ignored them.

Comment: `#define , ` ? hahaha only if you never need commas anywhere else. is that even legal?

Comment: Note that the lobbying is already in action: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3342.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a macro that would do it, tested on both MSVC and GCC. No reliance on Boost...

```
#define NUM(...) NUM_(__VA_ARGS__, , , , , , , , , , )
#define NUM_(...) NUM_MSVCHACK((__VA_ARGS__))
#define NUM_MSVCHACK(numlist_) NUM__ numlist_
#define NUM__(a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, a7_, a8_, ...) a1_##a2_##a3_##a4_##a5_##a6_##a7_##a8_
```

Use it like:

```
int y = NUM(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
int x = NUM(100,460,694);
```

Produces:

```
int y = 12345678;
int x = 100460694;
```

Comment: well this is close, preprocessory and boostless. if someone will be closer to "1_000_000" then I will change the answer again XD

Comment: and it's intelli-sense compatible (boost got an "error" on intelli sense but does compile)

Answer (score 38):

With a current compiler (C++14 or newer), you can use apostrophes, like:

```
auto a = 1'234'567;
```

If you're still stuck with C++11, you could use a user-defined literal to support something like: `int i = "1_000_000"_i`. The code would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int operator "" _i (char const *in, size_t len) { 
    std::string input(in, len);
    int pos;

    while (std::string::npos != (pos=input.find_first_of("_,"))) 
        input.erase(pos, 1);

    return std::strtol(input.c_str(), NULL, 10);
}

int main() { 
    std::cout << "1_000_000_000"_i;
}
```

As I've written it, this supports underscores or commas interchangeably, so you could use one or the other, or both. For example, "1,000_000" would turn out as `1000000`.

Of course, Europeans would probably prefer "." instead of "," -- if so, feel free to modify as you see fit.

Comment: +1. I was writing this, but you already did. Only problem with this solution is that `"1_000"_i` is a not constant expression anymore!

Comment: +1 for boostless approach, however this is @runtime, ofcourse a nice solution, VERY NICE, but a preprocessor solution would be excellent if it could be done this way : $

Comment: +1 for apostrophes in C++14 and newer. This feature should somehow be made more noticeable and possibly the answer nowadays.

Answer (score 13):

With [Boost.PP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/):

```
#define NUM(...) \
    NUM_SEQ(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)) 
#define NUM_SEQ(seq) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(NUM_FOLD, BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(seq), BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(seq)) 
#define NUM_FOLD(_, acc, x) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(acc, x)
```

Usage:

```
NUM(123, 456, 789) // Expands to 123456789
```

[Demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f3a85a4f81d001bc4911eeedca1b346f).

Another way is making an UDL. Left as an exercise (and also because it requires more code).

Comment: Post the usage example here, most people will be puzzled by this.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make an answer with self-written `printf`-like function doing this...

Comment: this is a really nice solution! Probbably the best C++ has to offer.. would love to see the ability to have 1_000_000 but okay, good enough :P

Comment: Using Boost-anything is probably more heavy-handed than patching the lexer in the compiler you're using... even if you need to apply binary patches to said lexer (it's not terribly hard to patch e.g. an old version of VS C++ compiler to dig the modern punctuation in integer literals).

Answer (score 5):

For *C++1y* you can now use single quote(`'`) as a digit separator. Based on [N3781: Single-Quotation-Mark as a Digit Separator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3781.pdf) which has [finally been accepted](https://twitter.com/stefanusdutoit/status/382945530722004992). Both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) have supported this feature as part of their *C++1y* implementation.

So the following program (*[see it live for clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1ddba4ef48570a2)*):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << 2'345'879'444'641 << std::endl ;
}
```

will output:

> 2345879444641

Answer (score 3):

You could use a preprocessor macro

```
  #define BILLION (1000*1000*1000)
```

then code e.g. `(4*BILLION)` ; if you care about large power of two just ust `1<<30`

PS Notice that `1e6` is a `double` literal (same as `1.0e6`)

And you could also:

1. patch the GCC lexer to accept `1_234_567` notation for number literals and publish that patch for conformance with GPLv3 and free software spirit.

   <sup>probably in file `libpp/lex.c` and/or `gcc/c-family/c-lex.c` and/or `gcc/cpp/lex.c` of future GCC 4.8, i.e. current trunk.</sup>
2. lobby the C & C++ standardization groups to get that accepted in future C or C++ standards.

Comment: it's not just about one billion, it's about ANY number

Comment: You can then write 2*BILLION+13*MILLION+120*THOUSAND+789 or similar.

Comment: Make it constexpr variable and maybe maybe maybe, using PP for constants is bad.