# the best way define a mask

Tags: c++, binary, mask

I write a function which should extract from `unsigned int` deferrent sets of bits.
I want to use a masks for that.I am not sure what is the best way to define such masks.
For example I need to extract bits 6:14.So I need to define a mask as  `111111111 << 6`.
My problem is I can't use boost or something like this and standard c/c++ doesn't know to work with binary numbers.
What is possible to do is to use 111111111 as 2^10-1.I am not sure - this is the best (most elegant ) solution.Any advices?

Comment: the problem is not clear enough. don't tell us about mask only, tell us also about the real problem.

Comment: You could use user-defined string literals for that. There was [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220217/) regarding large numbers recently.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537303/binary-literals ?

Comment: To create a mask for `2^10-1` you could use `(1<<10)-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `0x1FF << 6` (if you want `111111111 << 6`) or `0x3FF
<< 6` (if you want 2^10-1 << 6).  That's considerably clearer
than your binary.  As Jerry Coffin points out, you can easily
get 2^10 by using `1 << 10`, but I'm not convinced that this is
clearer than just using hexadecimal.  (For that matter,
in some contexts, `0x7FC00` might be perfectly clear.  It has
the advantage that you see visually exactly where the bits are
in the word, and it's easier to pick them out if you have a hex
dump.)

Answer (score 3):

Most people use hexadecimal when representing masks, such as 0xFF, 0x0A, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to make a bunch of ones first.

One property of a sequence of N ones in binary is that, just like a sequence of nines in decimal, if you add one to it, you get a one followed by a N zeros. We can use the inverse, the fact that if you subtract one from a one followed by N zeros gets you a sequence of N ones, to make that.

A one followed by N zeros is just 1 shifted right N places.

```
template <typename Uint>
Uint zigamorph(int n) { // http://catb.org/jargon/html/Z/zigamorph.html
    return 1 << n - 1; // same as 2^n - 1 :)
}
```

Armed with zigamorphs of any length, you can now get the bits you want from any value easily by using bitwise and.

```
template <typename Uint>
Uint mask_bits(Uint value, int first_bit, int last_bit) { // both inclusive?
    return value & zigamorph<Uint>(last_bit-first_bit+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the standard library? If so, I would try `std::bitset`

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) is the documentation for it.

Comment: If the question is tagged [tag:c++], you can safely assume that you can use standard library, unless explicitly stated otherwise.