# Nicely formatting numbers in C++

Tags: c++

In Ada it is possible to write numbers with underscores for separating digits, which greatly improves readability. For example: 1_000_000 (which is equivalent to 1000000)
Is there some similar way for C++?

EDIT: This is question about source code, not I/O.

Comment: I think there is no built-in function for this. Probably, you have to write your own function to do that.

Comment: That question ("Representing big numbers in source code for readability?") doesn't contain answer for me - it is using either boost or C++ 11 features.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of C++14, you can use `'` as a [digit group separator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#Single_quote):

```
auto one_m = 1'000'000;
```

Previous versions of C++ did not support this natively. There were two major workarounds:

- [Using user-defined literals in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220849/1968); this would allow you to write code as follows:

  ```
  auto x = "1_000_000"_i;
  ```

  (Writing this as a `constexpr` would be trickier – but is definitely possible.)
- [Using a straightforward macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220401/1968), which would allow the following code:

  ```
    auto x = NUM(1,000,000);
  ```

Comment: Since it is not possible for me to use the C++ 11 features I'm going to accept this answer (though I liked the solution with custom literal). Macro solution is quite nice.

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to do this currently. There is, however, a proposal to introduce [digit separators (N3499)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3499.html). They haven't yet chosen which character they'd like to use as a separator though. The current suggestions are:

- Space: `4 815 162 342`
- Grave accent: `` 4`815`162`342 ``
- Single quote: `4'815'162'342`
- Underscore: `4_815_162_342`

Unfortunately, they all have problems as described in the proposal.

You can take the hacky approach  by using a user-defined literal:

```
long long operator "" _s(const char* cstr, size_t) 
{
    std::string str(cstr);
    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ','), str.end());
    return std::stoll(str);
}
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "4,815,162,342"_s << std::endl;
}
```

This will print out:

```
4815162342
```

It simply removes all of the commas from the given literal and converts it to an integer.

Answer (score 5):

```
int main()
{
   int x = 1e6;
}
```

Comment: And what about things like : 0x40000000C00000D ?

Comment: Using scientific notation I can nicely write big numbers in decimal but numbers nondecimal will demand different solution.

Comment: That is true. For this, you can write a comment underneath, with pipes.

Answer (score 2):

you can always just define a variadic macro, used like `N(123,456,678)`. it's a bit more trouble than it's worth, though. in particular, you may have to workaround some visual c++ peculiarities for portable code for counting arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is perfectly possible by `imbue()`ing the I/O stream with the appropriate locale facet (in this case, [num_put](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put)).

(This is assuming you are talking about I/O. If you are talking about the source itself, that is not possible as of C++11.)

Comment: i think the question is about source code, not i/O

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: On second reading, I think you are right. Then again, you shouldn't use numeric constants in your source (much). ;-) I will leave this answer as-is, since neither the question nor its title is really clear about it (and others might actually look for I/O formatting).

Comment: @DevSolar When I'm having to choose between writing by hand 0x40000000 3 or more times I would rather declare it constant and use it. Beside it is quite hard to spot the lacking (or excess) zero with all these zeroes.

Comment: @darkestkhan: Yes, of course you declare it constant *once* and use the constant. So you have to make sure of the right number of zeroes *once*. (Perhaps via an aligned comment above indicating the number of digits? Or by using `1 << 30` instead?) I do see where you are coming from, and my comments that the lack of digit separators isn't that much of a pain are merely my personal opinion on the matter.

Comment: @darkestkhan: As for your edit, I did *mean* "as of". Making a string literal with separators be converted into an integer by means of user-supplied code isn't the same thing as writing an integer literal with separators IMHO.

Comment: @DevSolar ok, but then it doesn't make any kind of sense because it is not possible before C++ 11 in the first place so "as of" doesn't make sense (in fact it says that it was possible before)

Comment: @darkestkhan: Arg, language barrier... "up to and including"?